# How to block google analytics spam from hulfingtonpost.com?

Tags: google-analytics

Lately my Google Analytics is getting bombared with fake searches, referrals from `ilovevitalli.com, resellerclub.com, hulfingtonpost.com and apple.com`.

One of my sites shows search results like these in it's analytics widget:

[image]

How can I block these fake referrals and searches once and for all? I have set filters in Google Analytics but they keep showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't depend on your filter. This is categorized as organic traffic, not referral. They are long-tail keywords.

You should exclude these using the Search term exclusion https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795833?hl=en

Copy and paste these longtails. You can also exclude every keyword that contains "iloveitaly.com", not only exact match.

Another solution is to block access through ht.access

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} otherdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-referrer/

Comment: You gave a good answer, however, this question is actually loaded. Please see: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers/75914#75914 I am telling you this for your information so that you can help spread the word.