# Mozilla Compatible Agent

Tags: google, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics and i have a problem with Mozilla Compatible Agent - see the screenshot:
[image]

This is a screenshot of the Mozilla Compatible Agent with "Cities" as second Dimension.
The problem is, that i'm very sure, that the MCA coming from Ashburn is a "crawler" or "bot" (I'm sure because it visits the site in a certain interval and then leaves it very fast - and it only visits the sites that are in my sitemap.xml). I really want to filter this out because this is messing my statistics. What can i do? I don't want to filter out the complete MCA - only the one coming from Ashburn - any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For filtering out Ashburn's visitors, create a new segment with that browser and city as negative parameters. So it would be an "all visitors except these" segment. Then activate it in your reports.

But I think you should do more research before doing that.

Do you think all the hits from Ashburn are spammy? Try to add second dimensions to Location report. Look at source/medium, referral, hours, and organic search keyword (lot of times spammer bots access to your site with spammy keywords). Look at your server logs. There's a chance you can isolate that spammer bot and then filter it out in a cleaner way.

Look also at these two threads:
[How to block google analytics spam from hulfingtonpost.com?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76384/how-to-block-google-analytics-spam-from-hulfingtonpost-com/76390)
[How to fight off Google Analytics referrer spammers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers/75914#75914)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good answer! I will try it out tomorrow and and report you :)

Comment: I worked it out and i use a more specific filter now :)

Comment: Good. How did you identify it?