# Google Analytics is showing visits unrelated to my domain

Tags: google-analytics, web-traffic, google-analytics-spam

I recently set up a professional portfolio website on my own domain. After a few weeks of Google Analytics, I was surprised and even impressed to have such a high volume of traffic. However, it appears I am somehow recording traffic from a uni(dot)me domain that I want no association with (please see the image).

[image]
I'm concerned that from Google's view, the apparent association of my portfolio with this other site may negatively impact my search results or even offer search suggestions to this site.

I looked into @closetnoc's post on referral spammers ([How to fight off Google Analytics referrer spammers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers)) because one of the source cities is Samara. However, none of the web traffic from the other domains is actually referring on to my site. I am simply seeing a record of the traffic. Could this other site have copied or be using my analytics code? I don't want to visit the site in question to examine the source code.

While I can set up a new analytics account, I would appreciate suggestions on how to reduce the event of this occurring again.

Comment: This is where a server based website traffic log would be helpful. Compare log with GA....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all referrer spam, **there is no interaction with your website** at all. It hits directly Google Analytics and adds **fake data** as referrals, pages or keywords. To stop them **you should create a filter in GA**.

There are some related questions that may help you:

- About the "**share-buttons**": https://stackoverflow.com/a/29312117/3197362
- About "**darodar**" and Referrer Spam in General: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362
- About the **adult** referral:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29717606/3197362

Answer (score 1):

A new account will probably still get this referral spam "traffic."  One suggestion has been to change the last digit of you GA account from the default of "1" to another number.  But really, it's only a matter of time before these spammers start using those numbers too.

Your best bet at this point is to create filters in your GA account to filter this "traffic" out.

I detailed the steps I took to do just this in [this SE Webmasters post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77514/what-is-forum20-smailik-org-referral-traffic/78821#78821).