# Unexpected traffic from social-buttons.com

Tags: google-analytics, referrer, social-sharing-buttons

In [google-analytics](/questions/tagged/google-analytics) for my website, I noticed unexpected traffic referred by `social-buttons.com`. I don't use the social button code supplied by this website, However, I use addthis.com codes beside other custom apis from other social networks such as LinkedIn, twitter and Facebook.

The following is a screen shot for referral data in yesterday:

[image]

I tried to find any data on `social-buttons.com`, but it is just a simple page with code of their social buttons with no any additional information, so, I need to know any explanation for the cause of getting this traffic to my website.

Comment: Related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78582/interpreting-full-referrer-in-google-analytics/78586

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not valid traffic, it is called **Referrer Spam**, this kind of spam uses a Google Analytics weakness to make fake visits to your site, so they actually never visit your site.

**This Ghost Referrer Spam** targets random GA tracking ID's with the only purpose of getting traffic from people that get curious about the referral in their analytics and try to go to the site, so don't go there.

Here you can find more information about this specific Referrer Spam https://stackoverflow.com/a/29312117/3197362

The best thing to do is to **Exclude them from your Google Analytics**.You can find a couple of methods here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

Comment: What I have to take care: do this spamming, negatively, affect my website ranking? @Chavo

Comment: @sємsєм absolutely no effect on your rankings unless its slowing down your server or you have an exposed access log which is rare and doubtful.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about that affecting your ranking, [here is an explanation of Matt Cutts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLmO1GE4GvI) about this topic and to my knowledge this is still the same. The only thing you should worry about is your data, you should stop this Referrer Spam and check for more.