# Google Analytics listing hundreds of pages that are not from my site

Tags: google-analytics, spam, google-analytics-spam

lately i'm getting very strange pageviews in my GA report. On the tracked domain i have only 4 pages active. Instead of getting the report only for those pages i see 481 pages viewed on the tracked domain for the last month.

Actual pages are:

- /page1
- /page2
- /page3
- /page4

But in pageviews i get:

- /search.php
- /television.html
- /User/blog
- /it/
- /page1
- /category/Kitchen-Applainces
- /page2
- ...

Those pages are breaking my stats, avg. time, pageviews, uniques etc... I have tried setting up a filter with the following rules:

```
Include only --> Traffic to the subdirectories --> That contain --> /page
```

and applied Filter to available views.

The problem is that after applying the filer GA is not recording any of the visits or events. Is there another way i could filter out only my pages?

p.s. When I check the hostnames there are various domains listed.

Comment: What domain are they coming from?   My guess is that either some other site is using your tracking code, or a spammer is inserting them to get their message into one of your reports.     In either case, a domain name filter is usually a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, i've setup a domain name filter and for now it seems to be doing a good job of excluding those pages. Also the problem as you mentioned is that those sites are using the same tracking code, who would thought. If you create an answer i'll accept it :)

Comment: See also: [How to fight off Google Analytics referrer spammers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-google-analytics-referrer-spammers) and [Is there a way to get rid of Google Analytics event tracking spam?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81104/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-google-analytics-event-tracking-spam)   They are other similar Google Analytics spam problems solved with a domain filter