# Block social-buttons.com / simple-share-buttons.com Referral Spam

Tags: google-analytics, spam, spam-blocker, google-analytics-spam

How to remove social-buttons.com / simple-share-buttons.com this type of lots of Referral Spam link they increase 100% bounce rate [image: Google Analytic Screenshot]

How to remove this type of referral spam link in via .htaccess or Google Analytic

Comment: Answer to your question is here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78582/interpreting-full-referrer-in-google-analytics/

Comment: Dang, there seems to be a lot of the same questions in the last few days, both on here and SO!

Answer (score 10):

They use a **vulnerability in Google Analytics** to make **fake visits** so the only way to stop them for now, and until Google fix it, is to make a **filter in GA** since that is the source of the problem.

Blocking them in the `.htaccess` file **is pointless** since this kind of Spam never visits your site.

Check this answers for more information **about this spam** https://stackoverflow.com/a/29312117/3197362

And this for **Referrer Spam in General** and some methods you can use **to filter them** and **stop future occurrences** https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

As for the **previous/historical data**, you can use **segments** in Google analytics. Create a **REGEX** with the Spam names something like this:

```
social-buttons\.com|simple-share-buttons\.com
```

You can add as many as you want, but the REGEX has a 255 character limit. You can add multiple conditions if this happens

- Go to the **Reporting section** in your Google Analytics.
- In the lateral bar, expand **Acquisitions** > **All Traffic** and
  Select **Referrals**.
- In the main board Click on **+Add Segment**.
- Click on **New Segment**.
- Select **Conditions** Below Advanced.
- Set filter as **Exclude**. Change Ad Content for **Medium** and
  contains for exactly matches and type and select **referral** in the
  text box.
- Click on **AND**
- Change Ad Content for **Source** and contains for **matches regex**
  and paste the Spam Regex.

Comment: To defeat this specific type of referrer spam, instead of *excluding* traffic from a bunch different sources, I have an *include* filter that only allows traffic with Hostname matching my domain. My regex is something like `^((www|blog)\.)?mydomain\.com/?`. If you want to match any subdomain, just use `^((.*)\.)?mydomain\.com/?`.

Comment: Yes, that's also a good approach but you should add other like '|translate\.googleusercontent.com' and '|paypal\.com' (if you use it). It's fine for **small/ medium sites** but for large with a lot of subdomains can be tricky and can exclude some valid traffic. Here is something similar but with the filters http://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

Answer (score 1):

You can also just add a filter so that all traffic from these annoying sites are filtered out of your analytics and do not create fake results.

1. In Google Analytics go to Admin
2. Under VIEW select Filters
3. Add New Filter
4. Give the filter a name
5. Select Filter Type: Exclude
6. Select source destination: traffic to the host name
7. Select expression: that are equal to
8. Hostname: social-buttons.com
9. Verify and save.

This should filter out all their visits.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for spam referrals from free-share-buttons.com. The exclude does work for other referrals, though.

Comment: Try this:
After step 4, select Custom.
Check "Exclude".
Select "Referral" from "Filter Field" drop down.
Add in the free-share-buttons.com in "Filter Pattern".
Click Save.