# How to remove Google Analytics refferal traffic with unknown hostname using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-spam

I'm trying to remove ghost referral traffic in Google Analytics by excluding unknown hostnames coming to my site. 
This technique is described at: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/03/11/goodbye-to-exclude-filters-google-analytics/

The exclusion is done at Google Tag Manager saving `Pageviews` only when a custom trigger is fired. 
The custom trigger fires only when `Page Hostname` matches my domain hostname i.e.:

```
URL: http://www.example.com/page1.html
Page Hostname: www.example.com
```

(my domain is `example.com` in this example)

Trigger:

[image: Removing other domains at Google Tag Manager]

Tag:
[image]

But after creating the trigger my Referral Google Analytics report after a few days still looks like this (smudged lines are my actual web site - these lines are ok):
[image: Ghost Referral in Google Analytics]

How is it possible that an unknown Hostnames like `4webmasters.org` or even `(not set)` are in the report when all the traffic must match my `example.com` hostname specified in the trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use Google Tag Manager to combat this spam.   Those spammers **don't ever visit your website**.   They inject bad data into your Google Analytics by pinging the Google Analytics tracker URL directly.

The question [Block social-buttons.com / simple-share-buttons.com Referral Spam](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78688/block-social-buttons-com-simple-share-buttons-com-referral-spam) has a good answer on how to block the spam.  It requires that you create a filter within Google Analytics.