# Why is this URL showing up in my Google Analytics report?

Tags: google-analytics

Why is this URL showing up in my Google Analytics report?

`site3.free-floating-buttons.com`

I'm seeing that in my Google Analytics report for a very low traffic website. I wonder if it is a marketer that wants to show up in my analytics  as a marketing strategy, or if the hits to my site are genuine, that is if a human clicked something and eventually landed on my page.

Comment: I have not seen this one and I have not updated my list in a while and I should soon, however, I wonder if it is another ghost referrer as explained here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers/75914#75914

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Sad.

Comment: It is possible that it is a referral from a social button, however, you will see that social buttons of some sort are in the list, if not mine then others on the net, and it could possibly be the same thing. And yes(!), you are exactly right! It is sad!! I, for one, am getting very tired of looking at these ghost referrals in my GA stats. They can be filtered, granted, or ignored, but still it is a major annoyance that Google should have solved by now. It seems they do not have the will just yet. Panda, Quality, News-trend, and other updates I guess take priority. But still. (sigh)

Answer (score 2):

This is just referrer spam.
There a lot of projects out there (semalt, iloveitaly,..) which are just grabbing your Analytics ID to spam it.
This is sometimes seen as "Marketing" to get more visits on their page. Sometimes they are using it to get you on there "infected" homepage to share some malware with you.

See:

- [Block social-buttons.com / simple-share-buttons.com Referral Spam](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78688/block-social-buttons-com-simple-share-buttons-com-referral-spam)
- [How to fight off Google Analytics referrer spammers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers)
- [Interpreting Full Referrer in Google Analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78582/interpreting-full-referrer-in-google-analytics/)