# Why does Google Analytics report that I have traffic at a calculator.php URL for my blog?

Tags: google-analytics, php, web-crawlers, traffic, google-analytics-spam

I frequently see this URL having traffic via Google Analytics although I don't have any page and with that strucuter either.

URL - techanger.com/**calculator.php?get=windows-8-1-download-link-product-key**

The bold part is what I don't understand. It does not exist on our website. Is that a glitch?

Comment: Just make sure your server gives a `404` for non-existing pages

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is happening and how people are finding the link because I have tried searching for **techanger** and the calculator.php page hasn't shown up. I then searched for **techanger calculator.php**. I'm sure it's nothing to worry about because the 404 not found page that it brings me to isn't your own custom one.

The only thing that I can think of is that they are accessing it from another website. I think Google Analytics tells you what site the users are accessing this link from.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that that this is caused by analytics spammers.  Spammers have found that they can insert fake data into your analytics without ever hitting your site.    Many of them are doing so to put their own website names into the referrer report.   See: [Interpreting Full Referrer in Google Analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78582/interpreting-full-referrer-in-google-analytics)