# vitaly rules google - How to block spam referral traffic

Tags: htaccess, spam-blocker

Today I saw keyword in Google Analytic, which is:

vitaly rules google☆*:.｡.゚゚･*ヽ(^ᴗ^)丿*･゚゚.｡.:*☆ ¯_(ツ)*/¯(•ิ*•ิ)(ಠ益ಠ)(ಥ‿ಥ)(ʘ‿ʘ)ლ(ಠ_ಠლ)( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)ヽ(゚д゚)ノʕ•̫͡•ʔᶘ ᵒᴥᵒᶅ(=^. .^=)oo

Location is showing **Samara** in GA, I would appreciate if someone can tell, how to block this spammy traffic via .htacccess file?

Comment: This is definitely ghost referral spam hitting your GA account directly.  Editing .htaccess will have no effect.  See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers/75914

Answer (score 2):

Just create a valid hostname filter in GA. 90% of the spam will never bother you again.  Read the section on Ghost Referrals:

http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/

Comment: But how can I block this traffic in .htaccess. I even dont know domain name of this spammy traffic

Answer (score 1):

This type of spam **never accesses your site** so blocking it in your htaccess file won't have any effect. To keep clean your GA you should **stop it with filters** You can either use the hostname solution Mike suggests or add filter for it.

> - Go to **Admin tab** in Google Analytics
> - Select the **View** you want to filter > **Filter** > **New Filter**
> - In *Filter Type* choose **Custom Filter** > Exclude Filter
> - *Field*: **Campaign Term**
> - *Filter Pattern*: Enter **Vitaly rules google**

You can check this 2 related answers for **more info about Referrer Spam**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29717606/3197362

Comment: But how can I block this traffic in .htaccess. I even dont know domain name of this spammy traffic. As you can see there are weird characters

Comment: You **can't block this traffic from the .htaccess file**, this type of spam attacks directly GA, it never accesses your site. You can find more on the links provided here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30177813/3197362. I strongly recommend you to use the valid hostname filter that will get rid of most of the spam.