# How can I remove referral spam using a .htaccess file?

Tags: google-analytics, htaccess, referrer

I have three websites on various topics, but I can't decrease the bounce rate for them. Some spam referrers have been increasing my site's bounce rate day-by-day.

[image]

How can I remove this type of referral spam via a *.htaccess*? Can you provide an example for one such referrer?

Comment: There are many reasons of bounce rate increase? Did you check all?

Comment: can u explain me about reasons? I need solutions soon.

Comment: Kindly check : https://qualaroo.com/beginners-guide-to-cro/reducing-bounce-and-exit-rates/

Comment: These are ghost referrers and cannot be blocked. See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers/75914#75914