# .htaccess Solution to Referral Spam not working

Tags: htaccess, google-analytics-spam

Getting hit up with a new referral spam site (site valuation dot org) this morning and I've put my usual .htaccess fix in place:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*sitevaluation\.org\ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*best-seo-offer\.com\ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*buttons-for-your-website\.com\ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*4webmasters\.org\ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working as I still see the URL sitting there stubbornly in my GA real time overview.  Am I doing something wrong or is this site doing something to get around this?

Comment: You cannot block these. See this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers/75914#75914

Comment: Thank you, so they are spamming javascript to show up in GA rather than hitting the website.  Explains why the htaccess solution doesn't work.

Comment: Yep. That is exactly how it works. It is annoying as snot too! These spammers are getting bolder and bolder. I have gotten nearly 80 just yesterday. Some are outright ads. Google will have an answer at some point. We just have to be patient until then. I have to admit losing my patience once or twice.

Comment: Yeah, I saw one spam site hit every single one of my sites several hundred times at almost the same time last week, it's certainly getting more prevalent.  Very annoying.  I like watching my real time GA and seeing the referral spam there makes me want to rage at someone :)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Anytime! We are here for you anytime you need us. There are some real experts here too!!