# spam referers bypass htaccess rules

Tags: htaccess, web-crawlers, spam, referrer, botattack

Here is a sample code I'm using in .htaccess to block spam referers:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*buttons-for-your-website\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*free-social-buttons\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F,L]
```

Also, I have the following code in nginx configuration because I have nginx stands as a reverse proxy in front of apache:

```
if ($http_referer ~ "buttons-for-your-website\.com|free-social-buttons\.com")  
{ 
  return 403;
}
```

I'm still getting hits from `buttons-for-your-website.com`, by some way this bot can bypass all previous rules and I have no clue how. I've verified both htaccess rules and nginx configuration on a domain of mine and they blocked access to my website from that domain. So, how these bots are still able to visit my website? Appreicate your answers.

Comment: You will want to see this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers/75914#75914

Comment: Are these "hits" in your server access logs? Or in Google Analytics? If the later then see closetnoc's comment above. Possibly academic, but your .htaccess `RewriteCond` pattern is too specific, you only need a regex like: `buttons-for-your-website\.com` (like you have for nginx) or even just `buttons-for-your-website`.