# Uninstalled Google Analytics Tracking Code Still Receiving Data

Tags: seo, analytics, tracking

My company recently relaunched our website. In the months following the relaunch, we saw traffic drop dramatically. After poking around the website, I realized that the designer never installed the Google Analytics tracking code from the old website. However, the code has been receiving data over the last few months - the majority of it referrer spam or direct traffic to the homepage. Can anyone help me figure out how/why the code is still tracking data when it isn't installed on the site?

Comment: I have not updated the list in a while... but this answer probably explains how it all works: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers/75914#75914