# Visits to my site with a weird URL

Tags: google-analytics, advertising, visitors

Google Analytics shows visits to my site landing at: `mathematics21.org/?from=http://snip.to/`. I have not ordered advertisements from `snip.to` and have never seen a URL like this.

Comment: Check to see if these entries are in your server access logs. If not, then you want to see this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers/75914#75914 It is possible that this is another form of referral spam. Who knows for sure until you check your log files?? This is a new one.

Comment: @closetnoc It seems that there are no snip.to in my Nginx log files (except of one entry, probably originated from http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) - I will read that question.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering Spam(.)to in Google Analytics:

Step 1: Click on the ‘Admin’ tab on your GA web page.

Step 2: Choose which ‘View’ is to be filtered and then click the ‘Filters’ button.

Step 3: Click on ‘New Filter’.

Step 4: Write a name, such as ‘Spam Referrals’.

Step 5: On Filter Type choose Custom Filter –>Exclude Filter –> Field: Campaign Source–> Filter Pattern. Then on the Pattern, enter the domain name – Snip(.)to

Step 6: Select Views to Apply Filter.

Step 7: Save the filter, by clicking on the ‘Save’ button.

You are done! Congratulations!